# Any trick to get namespace for class in Angular using Visual Studio Editor?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

As I know Visual Studio, I am taking Visual Studio Editor as an example to ask my doubt in Visual Studio Code Editor.

If I need namespace for `SqlConnection`, all I need to do is to press **Ctrl + period** keeping cursor under `SqlConnection`. Visual Studio imports the right namespace perfectly at the right location.

But, I could not use the same or similar technique to get namespace for `Injectable` class (of course; I know that for `Injectable` class, `@angular/core` is the namespace.) in Visual Studio Code Editor for Angular.

Tomorrow, if I need to get namespace for `of` class, how can I know which namespace should be imported? **Is there any technique to import without the need to remember for the same!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is plugin for almost anything you need in VS Code.
Most likely you are looking for this extension https://github.com/soates/Auto-Import. It can automatically import the used type etc. It is very useful.

PS: Also make sure that you allow automatic sorting of imports on file save. It is also very handy

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.organizeImports": true
},
```

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio you'd click "Ctrl + .", in VS Code it's "Ctrl + Space Bar".  However you can modify this to your selection of choice in the settings for keyboard shortcuts.

You should take the point of view that there is an extension for everything.  You can import Visual Studio settings as well.

If you're missing namespace intellisense, it's quite possible that your project is missing the typings definition for that library.